# How can I make changes to Django import_export csv file before I export it without making changes to database

Tags: django, django-import-export

How can I edit the csv file before exporting using Django `import_export`? I know I can call `before_export` to do stuff with the queryset before exporting, but I specifically want to change all of a given integer field to "0" for the csv rows only and not make changes to the database.

```
class AdminResource(resources.ModelResource):
    def before_export(self, queryset, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        # I can only edit the queryset here but I need to edit the rows of the csv and leave the database
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`dehydrate()`](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#advanced-data-manipulation-on-export) method for this.  For example, if you wanted to set the 'price' field to zero, you can set declare your resource as follows:

```py
class BookResource(resources.ModelResource):

    def dehydrate_price(self, book):
        return 0

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'price')
```

Run with:

```py
    dataset = BookResource().export()
    print(dataset)
```

Result:

```
id|name      |price
--|----------|-----  
20|Triangles |0    
21|Rectangles|0
```